# How to make "show all parents and only children of current page" sidebar in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Making website with wordpress that has sidebar menu, that creates automatically list of pages with these settings. Shows all parent pages. Shows children and parents of current page. This structure needs to show on all depths.

Problem. Need advice how to get sidebar menu to show pages as in example below.
Everything is made by hand in PHP, CSS. Plugins are out of the question.

```
Example 1: (Current page is sub page 3):

-page1
    -sub page 1
    -sub page 2
    -sub page 3
        -sub article 1
        -sub article 2
-page2
-page3
-page4

Example 2 (current page is page1):

-page1
    -sub page 1
    -sub page 2
    -sub page 3
-page2
-page3
-page4
```

Below is example how we managed pages to show now and codes in PAGE.PHP and FUNCTIONS.PHP that we have right now. Code is in such state that it shows all the pages of that current "depth".

```
Like this (if current page is one of parents:

-page1
    -sub page 1
    -sub page 2
    -sub page 3
        -sub article 1
        -sub article 2

-page2
    -sub page 1
    -sub page 2
        -sub article 1

-page3
    -sub page 1
    -sub page 2

-page4
    -sub page 1
    -sub page 2

Or if current page is sub page it shows like this (shows no parents):

    -sub page 1
    -sub page 2
    -sub page 3
```

page.php

```
<?php
if ($post->post_parent) {
    $page = $post->post_parent;
} else {
    $page = $post->ID;
}

$children = wp_list_pages(array(
    'child_of' => $page,
    'echo' => 0,
    'title_li' => ''

));

if ($children) {
    echo "<ul>\n".$children."</ul>\n";
} 
?>
```

functions.php

```
function wpb_list_child_pages() { 

global $post; 

if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )

$childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . 
$post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
else
$childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . 
$post->ID . '&echo=0' );

if ( $childpages ) {

$string = '<ul>' . $childpages . '</ul>';   
}

return $string;

}

add_shortcode('wpb_childpages', 'wpb_list_child_pages');
```

Comment: Couldn't you just add the navigation menu widget to your sidebar? Wordpress adds a "current_page_item" class to the li of the currently opened page so the rest would just be a bit of CSS (hide sub-menu children and show them if current_page)?

Comment: Yes. We had problem with menus coz whole site is fully custom and another problem elsewhere made applying widgets a problem. Now it's solved and we used widget for this problem. It solved everything. Thank you for your time.